# python pyfits, reading header information and using in calculation

Tags: python, header

I am running some code with python and pyfits and I am reading out a line of information from the header. I am getting the correct line but due to how it is written in the header it is printing out with colons separating the numbers I need.

the line I am running is
print header[0].header['opp']

this prints
34:04:32.04

I need to do a calculation where I add these numbers together, but do not know how to do this as they are separated by colons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should solve your problem:

```
header[0].header['opp'] = "34:04:32.04"
print (sum(float(x) for x in header[0].header['opp'].split(":")))
```

... which outputs:

```
70.03999999999999
```

(EDIT)

Or, if the values actually make up a time in hours, minutes and seconds:

```
s = "34:04:32.04"
ss = [float(x) for x in s.split(":")]
print (ss[0] + ss[1]/60 + ss[2]/3600)
```

... which outputs the value in hours:

```
34.07556666666667
```

Comment: amazing thank you, the actuall calculation i need to do is, 
34+4/60+32.04/3600
is it possible to do this?

Comment: List comprehensions are wonderful things. I've amended my answer to do the calculation you need.